# Custom warning on when viewing cart (anonymous users)

Tags: users, commerce

I am wondering with what mechanisms it would be possible to add a warning message to anonymous users viewing their cart saying: "Please log in with any of the listed services in order to proceed to checkout".

If possible I'd like to avoid changing the module's code in order to avoid future update problems.

Thanks for any help,
Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is overriding a default cart page template (cart page has been created with Views module, name - 'commerce_cart_form', display - 'default');

1. Create a template for Style Output
2. Copy the content of it
3. Views module provides `logged_in` variable in `template_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)` function, so you can check with that variable and display a text;

example (`views-view-table--commerce-cart-form--default.tpl.php`):

```
<?php if (!$logged_in): ?>
  MY MESSAGE FOR THE ANONYMOUS
<?php endif; ?>

<table <?php if ($classes) { print 'class="'. $classes . '" '; } ?><?php print $attributes; ?>>
  // Rest of code from Style Output
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer! I have found the view, and figure that I could add the message, right? Unfortunately I'm totally lost on the first step: Create template for Style Output. Since I dont know what it is I don't find where I could do that.

Comment: @dmeu Open the 'Commerce cart form' in Views UI, expand `Advanced` section, open `Theme:Information`, copy the last template suggestion from `Style Output` section, paste it into your theme's folder (`views-view-table--commerce-cart-form--default.tpl.php`), click the StyleOutput link again, copy the code and put it into your created file, save the view, clear the cache, that's it. After that you can modify that template as I mentioned above.

Comment: @dmeu Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Cfc11_sb5M) which shows how to theme a views..

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, found it! Very useful. Meanwhile I have discovered the php views module which enables me to add your proposed code as a field in the footer. Thanks for your help!